# Google Docs PDF export has extra blank pages at the end of the document

Tags: google-docs

I use G Suite at work. I want a stand-alone PDF version of the Docs document I am editing. When I export a 4-page document, I end up with a 6-page PDF. The 5th and 6th pages are blank. Why? Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Extra carriage returns at the end of the document?

Comment: No, none that I can find and delete.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the [Google Doc help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/xlsQWxgdZJc), there are a few answers suggesting to change the view to "print layout". Changing the view to "print layout" fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: this worked great. my only problem is going to be remembering this tip and instead googling for this answer every time

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue you had, and tried all the suggested solutions with no results. Here is what ended up working for me:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select the entire document)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut the entire document out)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste the entire document back in)

Comment: Inconceivable! This actually worked :)

Comment: this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect solution:
Go to Print Preview -> Advanced Settings -> Margins, then make sure they are either default or none. The custom or minimum setting will cause a blank page to be inserted between every used page.

Credit goes to Sean Shrubsole for this brilliant answer at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ANASFcb3_UE: "I was experiencing the same issue ... i changed teh Print Margins from Minimal to Default and teh blank pages were removed." I just wanted to pass the information along.

Answer (score 1):

View - Print Layout (Ensure Print Layout is selected)

Works everytime - do not bother with the other workarounds as they do not address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

View > Print Layout was already ON for me already. So, changing Paper size from Letter to A4 make the extra blank page disappear. Worked for me.

**File > Page Setup > Paper Size to A4.**